# From local Excel sheets into dashboard online

Tags: data-structures, data-science

I have around 30000 sheets of excel with standardized report.
The goal is to provide online dashboard to view the data.
My first thought as programmer is to create a database and find a way to import the data and then build front end on the top to create a customized dashboard.
Any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your reports are always going to be in excel, I don't think it would be a good approach to convert them to a database. It will only add an overhead of converting the data and creating the frontend for it, that would be an overengineering.

Instead what you can do is you can use data visualization tools like `retool` which already offer visualization components on top of any source data. The source can be anything be it an excel sheet or a database.

There are other alternatives as well like `redash` which also offers connections to CSV files.

However, if you still feel that creating a database like MySQL or any other database of your choice is a better approach to go. Then you should consider using `Metabase` or `superset`. These are excellent tools for data visualization and only require the database credentials to connect to the DB. These are feature-rich, accepted within the industry and you can create possibly all the visualizations as per your need.

Also, the best part is all the tools that I have mentioned here are totally **open source** or have a nice trial period.

FYI, For a better and more effective solution, I would recommend running a `SQL Server` on your machine and uploading the `excel report` to the `SQL server` and then connecting the `SQL server` instance to the `Metabase`, That would do everything that you need and you don't have to spend time to write any code to manage all these stuff. Below is a glimpse of a `Metabase` Visualisation Dashboard:
[image]